# I want to copy files from one folder to another in my dedicated server

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I placed files in my root folder and copy when user try to download the files
like

> /root/filelocation/file.mp3

when user on download page

```
copy("/root/filelocation/file.mp3","download/file.mp3");
```

i use this command but it takes too much load time

i have ffmpeg installed in server also

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy it.  Make a symlink.  This is almost instantaneous.

Really though, you should consider why you're making a copy in the first place.  A simple script can call the appropriate `sendfile` function on your web server.  Or, you can get crafty with your rewrite rules and you might not have to copy or symlink anything.

Also, don't recommend using the root user's home directory.